# How to escape a string properly in nginx configuration file?

Tags: nginx

I'm looking into writing the following string into nginx.conf

```
construct { <https://data.elsevier.com/lifescience/entity/pp/pk/pkassay/1007> ?p ?o} where {{<https://data.elsevier.com/lifescience/entity/pp/pk/pkassay/1007> ?p ?o}UNION{graph ?g {<https://data.elsevier.com/lifescience/entity/pp/pk/pkassay/1007> ?p ?o}}}
```

as in:

```
location /lifescience/ {
                       rewrite \/lifescience\/entity\/(.+)$ '/IntegrationHub/query?query=\"construct { <https://data.elsevier.com/lifescience/entity/$1> ?p ?o} where {{<https://data.elsevier.com/lifescience/entity/$1> ?p ?o}UNION{graph ?g {<https://data.elsevier.com/lifes\
cience/entity/$1> ?p ?o}}}\"' ;
                       proxy_pass http://localhost:xxxx;
                 }
```

nginx accept my rewrite rule as in it is valid syntax in the conf file, but then when i hit it, it says that it is a bad request with error 400.

I wonder if someone could help me escape  the thing properly ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Thank you for the reply but why should I use that here ? I mean nothing says that I should. It is mandatory for form but otherwise not. I mean from what I gather.

Comment: More importantly how would you do that in nginx ?

Comment: It's what you asked for. You can do it manually or with an online service, of which there are several.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you so much for taking the time. But i am not sure to understand you well. What i asked is the rule of escaping string written in ngix to respect its syntax. It seems however that you are implying that the issue is not nginx syntax, but the fact that my string is not percent-encoded. My question now, is why should it be percent encoded? Is it the rule when making a Get request which contain funky characters ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. Your URL must conform to the syntax of a URL, which means that various characters must be percent encoded.

Comment: Ok now i understand better. Meanwhile, which part need to be percent encoded in my case. Only the query or the all thing from "/IntegrationHub/.....". Not that there are variable in my query content e.g. $1. If i use an only tool, then the expansion will not work out. Hence, could you give some advise on how to go about it ?